# MVC Bootstrap tooltip using Model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, tooltip

I am using MVC 4 and in my view I want to be able to use the model's error property to display a tooltip over the Error label.

`<label type="label" class="label label-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" title=@Model.Error>Error</label>`

If the error is, "Unable to locate file.", all that is displayed on the tooltip is the first word, "Unable".  It seems as though once a space is encountered it does not display anymore of the string.

What can I do to get the tooltip to display the whole string?

Comment: `title="@Model.Error"` (quotes)

Comment: thanks, that's does it.